# CompletableFuture not calling static methods in other Beans

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

This is one of my first posts, please forgive me if it is not formatted properly or giving the correct information, but I have been searching for the answer for days and still cannot figure it out.

I have a test where I am using Spring to inject beans. I need to run multiple API calls simultaneously, so I used CompletableFuture to do it. But when I do that, it seems that all static methods in a Utility class that are called in other components don't get called at all. The thread just stops and no error messages or anything, but using logging, I traced it to when the static method is being called.

I see that in all the beans, everything is being injected properly, but just when it his that static method, it just stops. If I test without CompletableFuture, it works just fine. I have been spending days trying to figure this out and I just can't find a good way to seemingly test the code using unit testing.

I have a thread that calls a service bean that is injected with properties which works fine, then it calls another service bean "JobService"

Test class:

```
@EnableAsync
class BillingRevenueVsExpensesServiceTest {
    private final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Test
    public void getBillingRevenueVsExpenses() {
        LOGGER.info("1 Starting Thread");
        ApplicationContext billingRevenueVsExpensesServiceThreadContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThreadConfig.class);
        ApplicationContext topLevelOwnerDataServiceThreadContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TopLevelOwnerDataServiceThreadConfig.class);

        BillingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread = billingRevenueVsExpensesServiceThreadContext.getBean(BillingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread.class);
        TopLevelOwnerDataServiceThread topLevelOwnerDataServiceThread = topLevelOwnerDataServiceThreadContext.getBean(TopLevelOwnerDataServiceThread.class);
        try {
            CompletableFuture<String> billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThreadCompletableFutureJsonString = billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread.getData();
            CompletableFuture<String> topLevelOwnerDataServiceThreadCompletableFutureJsonString = topLevelOwnerDataServiceThread.getData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service("jobService")
public class JobService {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    int spacesToIndentEachLevel = 2;

    //Injected Fields
    private final String baseURL;
    private final String portfolioID;
    private final String portfolioType;
....
    public String getJobID(String viewName, String viewID,  String timePeriod) {
        LOGGER.info("7 Starting job name: " + viewName + " view ID: " + viewID);
// CALLS BELOW METHOD IN THE SAME CLASS
        String[] timePeriodList = timePeriodCreator(timePeriod);
        //DOES NOT CONTINUE IN THE ABOVE

....
    private String[] timePeriodCreator (String timePeriod) {
        String[] timePeriodList = new String[2];
        Date date = new Date();
        LOGGER.info("Todays Date: " + date);

        switch (timePeriod) {
            case "previousEndOfMonthCurrentEndOfMonth" -> {
                LOGGER.debug("In the timeperiod utlity");
                timePeriodList[0] = DateUtilities.getPreviousYearMonthDate(date);
                timePeriodList[1] = DateUtilities.getEndCurrentYearMonthDate(date);
                LOGGER.debug("9 Timeperiod produced: " + timePeriodList[0] + " to " + timePeriodList[1]);
....

        return timePeriodList;
    }
```

Here is my Date Utilities class:

```
public final class DateUtilities {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DateUtilities.class.getName());

    final static DateFormat yearMonthDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    // Gets the previous months end date
    public static String getPreviousYearMonthDate(Date date) {
        LOGGER.info("Getting Previous Month Date");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Date previousYearMonthDate = cal.getTime();
        return yearMonthDateFormat.format(previousYearMonthDate);
    }
....
}
```

ConsoleOutput

```
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] INFO com.operations.backend.services.JobService - 7 Starting job name: billingRevenueVsExpensesView view ID: 386839
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] INFO com.operations.backend.services.JobService - 7 Starting job name: topLevelOwnerView view ID: 392697
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] INFO com.operations.backend.services.JobService - 8 Generating job for view ID: 386839
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] INFO com.operations.backend.services.JobService - 8 Generating job for view ID: 392697
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] INFO com.operations.backend.services.JobService - Todays Date: Fri Jan 13 15:24:29 EST 2023
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] DEBUG com.operations.backend.services.JobService - In the timeperiod utlity
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] INFO com.operations.backend.services.JobService - Todays Date: Fri Jan 13 15:24:29 EST 2023
15:24:29.847 [poolThread-1] DEBUG com.operations.backend.services.JobService - In the timeperiod utlity
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It basically stops when its calling the static date method. If I just do a regular call as opposed to the CompletableFuture, it works fine. I changed some names around for the sake of posting.

EDIT: Here is my Thread Class that has the get data:

```
@Service("billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread")
public class BillingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread extends AddeparJobsAPICallService {

...

    public BillingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread(String viewName, String viewID, String timePeriod) {
        LOGGER.info("3 Thread Setting Thread Parameters: " + viewName + " " + viewID);
        this.viewName = viewName;
        this.viewID = viewID;
        this.timePeriod = timePeriod;
    }

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> getData() {
        try {
            LOGGER.info("4 Starting Addepar Jobs API Call Service: " + viewName + " " + viewID);
            jsonStringOutput = runJob(viewName, viewID, timePeriod);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(jsonStringOutput);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("ERROR");
        }
    }
```

Here is the AddeparCallService

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JobServiceConfig.class})
public class AddeparJobsAPICallService {




    public String runJob(String viewName, String viewID, String timePeriod) {
        LOGGER.info("5 Running Addepar API Jobs Call Service: " + viewName);
        ApplicationContext jobServiceContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JobServiceConfig.class);
        JobService jobService = jobServiceContext.getBean(JobService.class);

//        LOGGER.info("Generating view: " + viewName + " job ID for: " + viewID + " for timeperiod:" + timePeriod);
        String jobID = jobService.getJobID(viewName, viewID, timePeriod);
        LOGGER.info("Generated Job ID: " + jobID + " for view: " + viewName + " job ID for: " + viewID + " for timeperiod:" + timePeriod);
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Waiting for job generation 10 minutes");
            Thread.sleep(600000);
            //Puts the json output into the key: billingRevenueVsExpenses
            return jobService.getJobResults(jobID, viewName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Issue with: " + AddeparJobsAPICallService.class.getName() + " : " + e);
            return "Loading";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the code for the `getData()` methods which return the futures?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe altough i do not think its the reason for your problem

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I have added the getData() code in the post

Comment: There is a bit too much code, you should provide a [mre] instead. This might even lead you to the cause of the problem. If I had to guess, there is an exception thrown by your `DateUtilities`, and since you let the program terminate, it just does not have the time to print anything before stopping. Also, you should have a single `ApplicationContext` and you should properly rely on dependency injection. Usually tests don’t even need to create the `ApplicationContext` as they just rely on some kind of `@SpringBootTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I got it. I went through each class and made sure I had the minimal annotations. I removed all of them and then added each of them testing to make sure it worked. And since I am trying to run everything in parallel. It looks like in order to use Completeable.allOf, I just converted the getData functions into a String return as opposed to a CompletableFuture and removed the @Async annotation:

```
    public TopLevelOwnerDataServiceThread(String viewName, String viewID, String timePeriod) {
    LOGGER.info("3 Setting Thread Parameters: " + viewName + " " + viewID);
    this.viewName = viewName;
    this.viewID = viewID;
    this.timePeriod = timePeriod;
}
```

I followed this to get the rest working and it is working in parallel now. Thank you all for the help!

https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-parallel-processing-with-completable-future

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace those 2 lines

```
CompletableFuture<String> billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThreadCompletableFutureJsonString = billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread.getData();
CompletableFuture<String> topLevelOwnerDataServiceThreadCompletableFutureJsonString = topLevelOwnerDataServiceThread.getData();
```

With

```
billingRevenueVsExpensesDataServiceThread.getData().get();
CompletableFuture<String> topLevelOwnerDataServiceThread.getData().get();
```

Looks like CompletableFutures created, but not executed.